# Using resolve without Promise

Tags: javascript, graphql

Till now, I have always used resolve with promise.

Initially, When I was studying about Promises, I read that we need to resolve the promise once we have the value.

Now, I was studying about GraphQL where the instructor using resolve without a promise i.e something like

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "RootQueryType",
    fields: {
        book: {
         args: { id: { type: GraphQLString }},
         resolve(parent, args){ 
            for (let i = 0; i<books.length; i++) {
                    if ( books[i]["id"] == args ) {
                        return books[i]["id"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    

})
```

So my question is, when do we use usually resolve or why have used resolve here.

I am watching this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed8SzALpx1Q&t=3010s) at around 52 minutes

Comment: Meaning this is wrong?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated the question.

Comment: this, graphQL `resolve` **is NOT related to promises** - just similar method name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I was studying about Promises, I read that we need to resolve the promise once we have the value.

Yes.

> Now, I was studying about GraphQL where the instructor using resolve without a promise

No.

They are defining a function *named* resolve.

`resolve` isn't a reserved keyword. It is just a name.

It is entirely unrelated to the function used to resolve a promise.

```js
const example = {
    resolve(a, b) {
       return a + b;
    }
};

console.log(example.resolve(1,2));
```

Comment: Gosh. That is just function/method name? I thought resolve is a reserved keyword. 
Got it, Thanks for answering.